# Numpy getting row indices of last two elements of each column in mask

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a boolean mask shaped `(M, N)`. Each column in the mask may have a different number of `True` elements, but is guaranteed to have at least two. I want to find the row index of the last two such elements as efficiently as possible.

If I only wanted one element, I could do something like `(M - 1) - np.argmax(mask[::-1, :], axis=0)`. However, that won't help me get the second-to-last index.

I've come up with an iterative solution using `np.where` or `np.nonzero`:

```
M = 4
N = 3
mask = np.array([
    [False, True, True],
    [True, False, True],
    [True, False, True],
    [False, True, False]
])
result = np.zeros((2, N), dtype=np.intp)
for col in range(N):
    result[:, col] = np.flatnonzero(mask[:, col])[-2:]
```

This creates the expected `result`:

```
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2]], dtype=int64)
```

I would like to avoid the final loop. Is there a reasonably vectorized form of the above? I am looking for specifically two rows, which are always guaranteed to exist. A general solution for arbitrary element counts is not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An argsort does it -

```
In [9]: np.argsort(mask,axis=0,kind='stable')[-2:]
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [2, 3, 2]])
```

Another with `cumsum` -

```
c = mask.cumsum(0)
out = np.where((mask & (c>=c[-1]-1)).T)[1].reshape(-1,2).T
```

Specifically for exactly two rows, one way with argmax -

```
c = mask.copy()
idx = len(c)-c[::-1].argmax(0)-1
c[idx,np.arange(len(idx))] = 0
idx2 = len(c)-c[::-1].argmax(0)-1
out = np.vstack((idx2,idx))
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that :)